# Quotient of a finitely generated torsion free abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: is a quotient of a finitely generated torsion-free abelian group still torsion-free?

Comment: No, you can consider $2\mathbb Z$ as subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the subgroup you quotient out by is pure, then yes it is.